# How to get a specific page of Task Executions from Spring Cloud Data Flow server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

**My Problem**:

I am working on an application using Spring Cloud data flow and Java. I am currently using a function called `executionListByTaskName(String taskName)` inside of my DataFlowTemplate's task operations. Then I use `.getContent()` to retrieve the collection of executions belonging to the task specified with "taskName". So I'm returning a `Collection<TaskExecutionResource>` from `DataFlowTemplate.taskOperations().executionListByTaskName(the-task-name).getContent()`. The problem with this function is that it will always retrieve the most recent 20 task executions. What I really want to implement is a function that when given two additional parameters, page number and task executions per page, will return the appropriate "page" of task executions. For example, if the page number was "2" and the size per page was "10," then I would return a collection of the 20th-30th most recent task executions.

**My Solution (that isn't efficient hence why I'm on stack overflow)**:

I was able to get a "page" by using the collection of TaskExecutionResources and the Page, Pageable, and PageImpl classes given by the Spring framework. I converted the collection into an ArrayList by doing `List<TaskExecutionResource> taskExecList = new ArrayList<>(taskExecColl)`. Then I created a Pageable object the standard way, taking into account of the provided page number and task executions per page. I create a `Page<TaskExecutionResource>` by creating a new PageImpl instance with the Pageable I created and the ArrayList of task execution resources. This works. However, converting the collection into an ArrayList is not scalable. The problem is, the underlying data structure of the collection is not a List of any sort, so i can't just cast it. If this is incorrect please let me know. Therefore, I don't know of any other way of implementing this pagination besides the solution above.

**My Question:**

Going through the DataFlowTemplate class, I found out that `dataFlowTemplate.taskOperations().executionListByTaskName(taskName)` calls a function in the TaskTemplate class.
Here is that function:

```
public org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.resource.TaskExecutionResource.Page executionListByTaskName(String taskName) {
    return (org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.resource.TaskExecutionResource.Page)this.restTemplate.getForObject(this.executionByNameLink.expand(new Object[]{taskName}).getHref(), org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.resource.TaskExecutionResource.Page.class, new Object[0]);
}
```

which in turn calls a function in the RestTemplate:

```
public <T> T getForObject(String url, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables) throws RestClientException {
    RequestCallback requestCallback = this.acceptHeaderRequestCallback(responseType);
    HttpMessageConverterExtractor<T> responseExtractor = new HttpMessageConverterExtractor(responseType, this.getMessageConverters(), this.logger);
    return this.execute(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestCallback, responseExtractor, (Object[])uriVariables);
}
```

What I want to know is what is the significance of the second parameter in these functions, `Class<T> responseType` which is set to `org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.resource.TaskExecutionResource.Page.class` by default. I can only imagine that TaskExecutionResource.Page.class is the reason why only the most recent 20 TaskExecutionResources are returned but I am not sure. Also, is there any way to replace this second parameter so that I can return specific pages of TaskExecutionResources. I have tried different things regarding this but couldn't get anything working. If anybody has some insight on this, or knows of another solution to this problem, please let me know. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the detailed write up. This looks like an enhancement to add in existing REST client implementation of SCDF or a bug to fix but it clearly requires some investigation. Could you create an issue here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues so that we can consider scoping/addressing it in the upcoming releases.Thanks!

Comment: Hey I just created the issue. It's my first time creating one so it may not be entirely clear or well formatted, but I hope it's understandable. If I may ask, there doesn't seem to be a solution to this question? Thank you.